# Exported web API controller disposed before calling action

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, mef

I have a web project which is ASp.net MVC and my controllers are mvc controllers for routing and api controllers.I'm using Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF).
and I just started login page which has mvc account controller and ap account contoller . the login page run and when I submit the user name and password it calls the api controller from angular controller and then it goes for the constructor of the api controller then call Dispose before calling my login action then Error page of resource can't be found Requested URL: /account/login
My login action using WebSecurity Class (WebMatrix.WebData)

Here is my BaseApi Controller

```
 public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController, IServiceAwareController
    {
        List<IServiceContract> _DisposableServices;

        protected virtual void RegisterServices(List<IServiceContract> disposableServices)
        {
        }

        void IServiceAwareController.RegisterDisposableServices(List<IServiceContract> disposableServices)
        {
            RegisterServices(disposableServices);
        }

        List<IServiceContract> IServiceAwareController.DisposableServices
        {
            get
            {
                if (_DisposableServices == null)
                    _DisposableServices = new List<IServiceContract>();

                return _DisposableServices;
            }
        }

        protected void ValidateAuthorizedUser(string userRequested)
        {
            string userLoggedIn = User.Identity.Name;
            if (userLoggedIn != userRequested)
                throw new SecurityException("Attempting to access data for another user.");
        }

        protected HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, Func<HttpResponseMessage> codeToExecute)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                response = codeToExecute.Invoke();
            }
            catch (SecurityException ex)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (FaultException<AuthorizationValidationException> ex)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

and here is my account Api controller

```
 [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    [RoutePrefix("api/account")]
    public class AccountApiController : ApiControllerBase
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public AccountApiController(ISecurityAdapter securityAdapter)
        {
            _SecurityAdapter = securityAdapter;
        }

        ISecurityAdapter _SecurityAdapter;


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]AccountLoginModel accountModel)
        {
            return GetHttpResponse(request, () =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                bool success = _SecurityAdapter.Login(accountModel.LoginEmail, accountModel.Password, accountModel.RememberMe);
                if (success)
                    response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                else
                    response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized login.");

                return response;
            });
        }


    }
```

and i register my mef extension class which handle MEF in the globa asax

```
 AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            CompositionContainer container = MEFLoader.Init(catalog.Catalogs);

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MefDependencyResolver(container)); // view controllers
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefAPIDependencyResolver(container); // web api controllers
```

and here is too my mef dependancy resolver class

```
public class MefAPIDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        public MefAPIDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
        {
            _Container = container;
        }

        CompositionContainer _Container;

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _Container.GetExportedValueByType(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _Container.GetExportedValuesByType(serviceType);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

i lost the plot . Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOps it is my fault .
it was about the html form which has an action to mvc controller and it doesn't exist 
so instead of

```
<form class="loginForm" action="@Url.Action("Login","Account")" method="post" name="loginForm">
```

so I replace it with

```
    <form class="loginForm" name="loginForm"> <!--Without action-->
    <!--and submit button-->
<button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right" ng-click="login()">
```